SSAS DSV logical primary key performance impact
TLDR: does setting up a logical primary key on a named query in SSAS DSV (data source view) have any performance benefits and, if so, which?

Named queries in SSAS DSV don't necessarily need a logical primary key in order for the dimensions/measures to use them. The DSV named queries also don't need a relationship between them.
I have found that adding relationships doesn't have any performance benefits. So my question is the same for the logical primary key: does adding it have any perf benefits?
I was only able to find one article that mentions that adding a logical primary key does improve performance:

In SSAS Data Source Views, logical primary keys and relationships are essential for data integrity and query performance

and

Logical primary keys and relationships can help you improve the performance, accuracy, and usability of your SSAS solutions

However, they don't explain how does it impact the performance (i.e. do they somehow add an index on those columns or what-have-you).

There's certainly nothing going on like actual indexes being created, or anything, when you define logical primary keys on a named query.  After all, the named query (and any associated keys, relationships) are just definitions within the DSV (which is, after all, just a big XML file).  Maybe the better question is - does defining the logical primary keys produce any MEASURABLE performance improvement?  Because, in reality, we can't tell exactly what's going on within the guts of SQL Server, so maybe it's possible that something is improved by having those keys defined? ..... I don't know
